# any matlab function for date (day-month-year)

Tags: matlab, date

How can I get the date from "30-4-2013 16:36:58" data with datastr or other function in matlab?

It gives me strange results, because the date is before than month.

yt = datestr('"30-4-2013 16:36:58"','dd-mm-yy')

yt = 04-10-35

The problem is I have bunch of data <112577x1 cell> and the raw data is like that: 
"4-2-2014 16:36:58"
"4-2-2014 16:37:03"
"4-2-2014 16:37:08"

Comment: Did you try mm-dd-yyyy? [link to reference](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/datestr.html)

Comment: I gives strange results also. yt = datestr('"30-4-2013 16:36:58"','mm-dd-yy')

yt = 10-04-35                                                             datestr understands the first data as month, I have to change into day, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a cell array, a variant on Bibek Subedi's answer will work:

```
out = datestr(datenum(C,'"dd-mm-yy HH:MM:ss"'),'dd-mm-yy');
```

You can change the second format string if you need some other output. Incidentally if you're getting that cell array by reading in a text file with something like `textscan` you should be able to read it in without the `"` by adding them as delimiters and treating multiple delimiters as one.

Answer (score 3):

By writing only 30-4-2013, MATLAB has no idea whether this is String or date? First convert it into the serial date number and then only convert it to date as bellow

```
>> datestr(datenum('30-4-2013 16:36:58','dd-mm-yy'))
```

This will give the result as

```
>> 30-Apr-2013
```

Comment: The problem is I have bunch of data <112577x1 cell> and the raw data is that:"4-2-2014 16:36:58"
"4-2-2014 16:37:03"

Answer (score 0):

Matlab syntax gets date in the american notation, which is: mm-dd-yyyy.
You get gibberish if you write dd-mm-yyyy, as in 30-04-2013.
Writing 30/Apr/2013 or 04-30-2013 fixes the problem and gives correct answers.

Comment: The problem is I have bunch of data <112577x1 cell> and the raw data is that:"4-2-2014 16:36:58"
"4-2-2014 16:37:03"